# Inner shadow with Core Graphics

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-graphics

Saw the generated code for drawing inner shadow. Everything is pretty clear and understood except for the portion whereby the shadow is created with ***copysign***.

I understand what ***copysign*** does but why and how is it actually being used in the code below.

The 0.1 value seem insignificant to the ***xOffset*** value.

```
  CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
  
  UIColor *shadow = [UIColor redColor];
  CGSize shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(-2, -0);
  CGFloat shadowBlurRadius = 2;

  UIBezierPath *rectanglePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect: CGRectMake(50, 50, 50, 50)];
  [[UIColor grayColor] setFill];
  [rectanglePath fill];
  
  CGRect rectangleBorderRect = CGRectInset([rectanglePath bounds], -shadowBlurRadius, -shadowBlurRadius);
  rectangleBorderRect = CGRectOffset(rectangleBorderRect, -shadowOffset.width, -shadowOffset.height);
  rectangleBorderRect = CGRectInset(CGRectUnion(rectangleBorderRect, [rectanglePath bounds]), -1, -1);
  
  UIBezierPath *rectangleNegativePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect: rectangleBorderRect];
  [rectangleNegativePath appendPath: rectanglePath];
  rectangleNegativePath.usesEvenOddFillRule = YES;
  
  CGContextSaveGState(context);
  {
    CGFloat xOffset = shadowOffset.width + round(rectangleBorderRect.size.width);
    CGFloat yOffset = shadowOffset.height;
    CGContextSetShadowWithColor(context,
                                CGSizeMake(xOffset + copysign(0.1, xOffset), yOffset + copysign(0.1, yOffset)),
                                shadowBlurRadius,
                                shadow.CGColor);

    
    [rectanglePath addClip];
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-round(rectangleBorderRect.size.width), 0);
    [rectangleNegativePath applyTransform: transform];
    [[UIColor grayColor] setFill];
    [rectangleNegativePath fill];
  }
  CGContextRestoreGState(context);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Developer of [PaintCode](http://www.paintcodeapp.com) here.

Shadows offsets are always "rounded" to integral pixels. Unfortunately, there is some sort of precision/rounding issue in Core Graphics. For certain values of shadow offsets, the rounding somehow goes off and an incorrect offset is used (for example, 2 instead of 3).

By strategically adding or subtracting 0.1 from the shadow offset, we force it to always behave correctly.